# Performing two different actions on the same day for an employee

Tags: abap, sap-hr

While performing this through PA40 it is overwriting the previous one, if I use HR_info_type operation it is creating the second record in additional actions. Why this behavior is different from PA40?

Answer (score 0):

Try use 302 infotype for additions actions.

http://saphr.iexpertify.com/2008/12/additional-actions-infotype-it0302.html